# Handling response from URLSession.shared.uploadTask

Tags: swift, upload, urlsession

i created an upload task which is working fine, i do get the correct response from my php file.

but i am somehow having trouble with using the data response received..

i expect a return string to be "7", but in fact i do get "7\n".
and i can't even split the string to convert "7\n" to int16 7.

```
    func validateUser(user: User) {
    (...)
        let url = URL(string: "exampleURL")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print ("error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print ("server error")
                return
            }

            if let mimeType = response.mimeType,
                let data = data,
                let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print ("got data: \(dataString)")   // "7\n"
                self.globalUserID = Int16(dataString) ?? 0      // always 0

                
                // proceed with usage of response
                }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

i also have some trouble understanding how to proceed with the return value after the function has completed,
so i try to use it directly inside the function (write into self.globalUserID)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can trim invalid characters, just replace them, or maybe a `NumberFormatter` might work.

Comment: yea, i tried multiple things already...f.e. Int16(dataString.prefix(1)) does work, but what if i get a number with 2 or 3 digits? so i have to search the string.index for the character "\", but because "\" is a special character i am having trouble doing so.. dataString.range(of: "\"") does not work too...why is there a "\n" anyway??

Answer (score 0):

i guess i've found a way:

```
print("String before: \(dataString)")  // "String before: 7\n"
let ID = Int16(dataString.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines).joined())
print("String after: = \(ID)")  // ID = Optional(7)
```

ID is still an optional, but so far so good :)

Comment: Simpler: `let ID = Int16(dataString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))` since you only need to remove whitespace from the ends, not in the middle of the string. Unless you want to convert a string such as `7\n7` into `77`. And `ID` will be optional whether you have to cleanup the whitespace or not. Consider the case where `dataString` contains "Hello".

Comment: yea, true! but as i control the feedback, which comes from my own API, this is not an issue! another alternative is ```Int16(dataString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")) ```